# updating information from the "about" section in recipe/meta.yaml

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, conda-forge

I maintain a conda-forge package ([spaghetti](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/spaghetti)) and I have a question regarding updating the information from the "about" section in recipe/meta.yaml from the conda-forge feedstock. After updating [`recipe/meta.yaml`](https://github.com/conda-forge/spaghetti-feedstock/blob/250900b33e78772851e10cb6780ab38b8dc969fb/recipe/meta.yaml#L34) the [`README.md` re-renders correctly](https://github.com/conda-forge/spaghetti-feedstock/blob/master/README.md) on the GitHub feedstock page, but it seems the updated information is not being pushed up to the actual [anaconda/conda-forge site](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/spaghetti). Does anybody know if there is something I can do to control this directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have resolved itself after a month or so.

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/spaghetti